# Is there a good reference org-mode template for output of learning content to markdown (online), as well as TeX (print) formats?

Tags: org-mode, writing

I'm working on converting a 200 page book (currently in TeX) to org-mode. Ideally I should be able to push the new org-mode variant of content to both markdown (for online learners) as well as to more sophisticated formats for print (read: LaTeX).

Is there a good best practice guide, or template for this?

What are the pitfalls of switching to org-mode as the primary format for content?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, and please keep it specific. Thx. The "pitfalls" question seems a bit too broad for this Q&A site - you might want to try that on a site like Reddit, which is more open to brainstorming and discussion. Both are good questions, BTW, and your conversion project sounds interesting.